# How to run many SVM Models with SAS Code?

Tags: sas

I'm working in Enterprise Miner, and saw [this video from SAS](https://youtu.be/EOxwpnbFqIU?t=18m20s), in which he briefly shows a SAS Code node to run a bunch of SVM Models.

He didn't show the whole thing, but enough to get me curious about how to do this. Here's what I was able to get so far:

```
%macro hpsvm (run=1,runLabel=,penalty=10,method=activeSet,kernel=TBF);

    proc hpsvm data=&em_import_data maxiter=25 metho = &method. tolerance=0.000001 c = &penalty.;
        input %em_internal_input / level = interval;
        target %em_target / level = binary ;
        lernel &kernel.;
        partition fraction (validate=.3 seed=12345);
        ods output fitStatistics=fitStats&run.;
    run;

    data firStats&run.;
        length method $ 10;
        length kernel $ 10;
        length runLabel $ 64;
        set fitStats&run.;
        run = &run;
        runLabel = "&runLabel";
        method="&method.";
        kernel="&kernel.";
        penalty=&penalty.;
    run;

    proc print data=fitStats&run.;
    run;

    proc append base=fitStats data=firStats&run.;

%mend hpsvm;

%hpsvm(run=1,runLabel=RBF c=1, method=activeSet, kernel=RBF,penalty=1);
%hpsvm(run=2,runLabel=RBF c=5, method=activeSet, kernel=RBF,penalty=5);
%hpsvm(run=3,runLabel=RBF c=10, method=activeSet, kernel=RBF,penalty=10);
%hpsvm(run=4,runLabel=RBF c=15, method=activeSet, kernel=RBF,penalty=15);
%hpsvm(run=5,runLabel=RBF c=20, method=activeSet, kernel=RBF,penalty=20);

%hpsvm(run=6,runLabel=Linear c=1, method=ipoint, kernel=linear,penalty=1);
%hpsvm(run=7,runLabel=Linear c=5, method=ipoint, kernel=linear,penalty=5);
%hpsvm(run=8,runLabel=Linear c=10, method=ipoint, kernel=linear,penalty=10);
%hpsvm(run=9,runLabel=Linear c=15, method=ipoint, kernel=linear,penalty=15);
%hpsvm(run=10,runLabel=Linear c=20, method=ipoint, kernel=linear,penalty=20);

%hpsvm(run=11,runLabel=Polynomial c=1, method=ipoint, kernel=POLYNOM,penalty=1);
%hpsvm(run=12,runLabel=Polynomial c=5, method=ipoint, kernel=POLYNOM,penalty=5);
%hpsvm(run=13,runLabel=Polynomial c=10, method=ipoint, kernel=POLYNOM,penalty=10);
%hpsvm(run=14,runLabel=Polynomial c=15, method=ipoint, kernel=POLYNOM,penalty=15);
%hpsvm(run=15,runLabel=Polynomial c=20, method=ipoint, kernel=POLYNOM,penalty=20);

%hpsvm(run=16,runLabel=Sigmoid c=1, method=activeSet, kernel=SIGMOID,penalty=1);
%hpsvm(run=17,runLabel=Sigmoid c=5, method=activeSet, kernel=SIGMOID,penalty=5);
%hpsvm(run=18,runLabel=Sigmoid c=10, method=activeSet, kernel=SIGMOID,penalty=10);
%hpsvm(run=19,runLabel=Sigmoid c=15, method=activeSet, kernel=SIGMOID,penalty=15);
%hpsvm(run=20,runLabel=Sigmoid c=20, method=activeSet, kernel=SIGMOID,penalty=20);

data fitStats;
    retain run runLabel method kernal penalty;
    set fitStats;
run;

%em_register(type=Data,key=fitStats);

data &em_user_fitStats;
    retain Penalty;
    set fitStats;
run;

%em_report(viewType=data,key=fitStats,autodisplay=y,description=Fit Statistics by Run);

%em_register(type=Data,key=Error);
```

A few things to note about this:

- I'm using the [MillionSongDataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/YearPredictionMSD) from UCI *(but let me know how to output data to a good format for SO, and I'll add some here)*
- This should run using data from the previous node (Data Partition)
- The only error I can make out is something about not having quotes or semi-colons in the right place, but everything looks ok to me (with almost no SAS Coding experience).
- He did not show the remaining 1/5th of the code.

I'm looking to run many SVM Models to try different combinations of options to find the best model.

Comment: Right now this isn't really manageable as a SO question.  It's both too big and has too little detail; you'd need to specify the specific errors, for one thing.  For another, this sounds like you need to do some more learning before attempting; this isn't trivial, and if you have basically no SAS coding experience, I would think that's more your problem right now.

Comment: @Joe You don't seem to know what you're talking about. Try using Enterprise Manager for a few weeks, and you'll get to this same point.

Comment: @TravisHeeter Do you mean Enterprise Miner? Or Model Manager? SAS EM is difficult to use, but I'm not sure how that relates at all to Joe's statement. I'm also not sure what your asking. The above code doesn't work? Before building a macro you should have working code and then add the macro variables step by step. There are several mistakes in your code, the most obvious being the missing run at the end, but that's not necessarily a fatal error either. You haven't posted a log with errors either....

Comment: Here's a post on how to create data for others to use in any forum. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/How-to-create-a-data-step-version-of-your-data-AKA-generate/ta-p/258712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS actually emailed me the code!

```
%macro hpsvm (run=1,runLabel=,penalty=10,method=activeSet,kernel=RBF);


   proc hpsvm data=&em_import_data maxiter=25 method = &method. tolerance=0.000001 c = &Penalty.;
     input  %em_interval_input / level = interval;
     target %em_target / level = binary ;
     kernel &kernel.;
     partition fraction (validate=.3 seed=12345);
     ods output fitStatistics=fitStats&run.;
   run;

   data fitStats&run.;
     length method $ 10;
     length kernel $ 10;
     length runLabel $ 64;
     set fitStats&run.;
     run = &run;
     runLabel = "&runLabel";
     method="&method.";
     kernel="&kernel.";
     penalty=&penalty.;
   run;

   proc print data=fitStats&run.;
   run;

   proc append base=fitStats data=fitStats&run.;
   run;

%mend hpsvm;

%hpsvm(run=1,runLabel=RBF c=1,method=activeSet,kernel=RBF,penalty=1);
%hpsvm(run=2,runLabel=RBF c=5,method=activeSet,kernel=RBF,penalty=5);
%hpsvm(run=3,runLabel=RBF c=10,method=activeSet,kernel=RBF,penalty=10);
%hpsvm(run=4,runLabel=RBF c=15,method=activeSet,kernel=RBF,penalty=15);
%hpsvm(run=5,runLabel=RBF c=20,method=activeSet,kernel=RBF,penalty=20);

%hpsvm(run=6,runLabel=Linear c=1,method=ipoint,kernel=linear,penalty=1);
%hpsvm(run=7,runLabel=Linear c=5,method=ipoint,kernel=linear,penalty=5);
%hpsvm(run=8,runLabel=Linear c=10,method=ipoint,kernel=linear,penalty=10);
%hpsvm(run=9,runLabel=Linear c=15,method=ipoint,kernel=linear,penalty=15);
%hpsvm(run=10,runLabel=Linear c=20,method=ipoint,kernel=linear,penalty=20);

%hpsvm(run=11,runLabel=RBF c=1,method=ipoint,kernel=POLYNOM,penalty=1);
%hpsvm(run=12,runLabel=RBF c=5,method=ipoint,kernel=POLYNOM,penalty=5);
%hpsvm(run=13,runLabel=RBF c=10,method=ipoint,kernel=POLYNOM,penalty=10);
%hpsvm(run=14,runLabel=RBF c=15,method=ipoint,kernel=POLYNOM,penalty=15);
%hpsvm(run=15,runLabel=RBF c=20,method=ipoint,kernel=POLYNOM,penalty=20);

%hpsvm(run=16,runLabel=Linear c=1,method=activeSet,kernel=SIGMOID,penalty=1);
%hpsvm(run=17,runLabel=Linear c=5,method=activeSet,kernel=SIGMOID,penalty=5);
%hpsvm(run=18,runLabel=Linear c=10,method=activeSet,kernel=SIGMOID,penalty=10);
%hpsvm(run=19,runLabel=Linear c=15,method=activeSet,kernel=SIGMOID,penalty=15);
%hpsvm(run=20,runLabel=Linear c=20,method=activeSet,kernel=SIGMOID,penalty=20);


data fitStats;
  retain run runLabel method kernel penalty;
  set fitStats;
run;


proc print data=fitStats;
run;


%em_register(type=Data,key=fitStats);

data &em_user_fitStats;
   retain Penalty;
   set fitStats;
run;

%em_report(viewType=data,key=fitStats,autodisplay=y,description=Fit Statistics by Run);

%em_register(type=Data,key=Error);

data &em_user_Error;
   set fitStats;
   if statistic = 'Error';
run;

%em_report(viewType=lineplot,key=Error,x=penalty,y=validation,group=kernel,description=Classification Error by penalty,autodisplay=y);


%em_register(type=Data,key=Sensitivity);

data &em_user_Sensitivity;
   set fitStats;
   if statistic = 'Sensitivity';
run;

%em_report(viewType=lineplot,key=Sensitivity,x=penalty,y=validation,group=kernel,description=Sensitivity by penalty,autodisplay=y);


%em_register(type=Data,key=Specificity);

data &em_user_Specificity;
   set fitStats;
   if statistic = 'Specificity';
run;

%em_report(viewType=lineplot,key=Specificity,x=penalty,y=validation,group=kernel,description=Specificity by penalty,autodisplay=y);
```